# Are class variables in Java shared between threads or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering when declaring a class variable (i.e. a variable declared outside a method) would potentially cause problems in a program that's executed by several threads. I suppose `final`s are save to use (i.e. not shared), and `static` variables are definitely shared between threads. But what about "standard" variables? When are they shared and when are they "private" to each individual thread?

**Update:** While I accept that local variables (within methods) are not shared and class variables usually are I would love to understand why that is (from a technical point of view). So any explanation to that effect (or links to articles that are fairly easy to understand) would be much appreciated.

Comment: It may be shared, or it may be not, depends on how you use it. Things are always like this.

Comment: Yes they are shared, so you have to handle exclusion with some primitives or if you can afford it use "synchronized" methods.

Comment: Threads don't share anything by themselves, you have to make them share whatever it is fields/properties.

Comment: This comes many years later but in case someone reads the question and wonders why local variables are not shared and class variables are. The reason is the JVM memory model and where the variables are stored. Class variables are stored on the heap, local variables on the stack. For details see for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-local-variables-thread-safe

Answer (score 7):

Java provides the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) class to declare variables that are not shared between threads. Non-`final` parameters and local variables are also not shared between threads. `final` parameters and locals variables may be shared between threads when they are used in an anonymous class definition, but this shouldn't be a problem since they are `final`. In all other cases I can think of, variables can be shared between threads.

Comment: (i) technically you can share a non final local variable across threads. You just need to pass it to a method that starts a thread (and will have a final parameter). (ii) parameters, whether final or not, might be shared or not depending on what the calling code does with them.

Comment: @assylias A separate thread cannot write back to or even directly access a parameter slot or the slot containing a non-final local variable. Obviously object instances can be shared between threads - that is always the case, but not what I'm talking about here. I'm talking about storage locations.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, any method or variable, both `static` and non-`static`, has the potential to be accessed by more than one `Thread` if its access modifier makes it visible to that `Thread`.

The concept of "thread-safe" is entirely different.  If a variable is read-only (`final` can be used to make primitives read-only, but only makes references to objects immutable, not the objects themselves), multi-threaded access of that variable is inherently thread-safe.  If it can be written to, the proper use of `synchronized` blocks or the `volatile` keyword is necessary to ensure mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about a standard variable that shields it from multi-threaded access and resulting problems.  That's up to YOU the programmer to worry about.

If two threads need to safely access the same instance fields, then YOU have to write code to manage that.

Some common techniques are to use synchronized blocks to manage mutability, using atomic or final primitives (a final Object is not necessarily safe unless you know the Object isn't mutable), or simply use a ThreadLocal to give each thread its own unshared instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Final doesn't mean 'not shared' just that the field cannot be overwritten, it can only be initialized one.
Static behavior is also not related to threading, static means that the field has a Class scope and not instance scope, meaning it's shared by all the instances of a Class.
If you want to protect a field from being modified by many threads, you have to manipulate it through synchronized methods.

Answer (score 0):

Such variables are called the *fields* of the class, and they are definitely **not** "thread-safe" in general, even when they are `final` (because `final` only refers to the reference itself, not what's inside the object).